# What is the main difference between AWS Docker and Hadoop Clusters?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, docker, cluster-computing

I am new to AWS and Big Data. I know the concept of cluster or Distributed Computing. If anyone can please shed some light on AWS Docker in relation to Hadoop Cluster. Thanks.

Comment: Docker itself has nothing to do with Hadoop...

Comment: I'm not sure there are even any similarities.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to explain this simply.

[Docker](https://aws.amazon.com/docker/) allows you to run, build, and test code within [Containers](https://aws.amazon.com/containers/). That's it. AWS has no specific part in that other than you can run Docker containers inside EC2 Container Service.

Notice how I said nothing about Hadoop or Big Data in that description. Your containers could contain *any* packaged application, be that a web server, database, build-tool, etc.

Now, Hadoop is able to be broken into containers by taking Hive, Hbase, Spark, the datanodes and namenodes, etc. and just putting each component into separate containers and linking them all together to form the ecosystem.

So instead of having a cluster of machines that are networked together, you have a cluster of containers which can be on *any* or *multiple* machines. Therefore, containers are much more scalable, lightweight, and portable by sharing the resources of the host machines rather than having dedicated hardware for each service.

Comment: I just realized how stupid the question was after doing some study on Hadoop and Docker. Thanks for the answer anyways. I will delete this question soon but it does have lot of views (22 in past day) so I will leave it here for now.